# unable to build a asp.net app in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

Able to build the app locally, but when am trying to build in azure devops pipeline.It showing below errors

I have installed EntityFramework and added system.data.entity.design assembly in webconfig file.No luck

[Please find pipeline here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN0NM.png)

[NuGet Restore task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBBS8.png)

```
webapp\CaseDatabase.DataAccess\CaseAssignmentModule\CaseQueueDbAdapter.cs(10,19): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
webapp\CaseDatabase.DataAccess\CaseAssignmentModule\HoursEstDbAdapter.cs(4,19): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
webapp\CaseDatabase.DataAccess\CasesModule\CaseWorkflowDbAdapter.cs(2,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
webapp\CaseDatabase.DataAccess\ClientsAndContactsModule\ContactDefaultsDbAdapter.cs(5,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
webapp\CaseDatabase.DataAccess\ClientsAndContactsModule\InstructionLibraryDbAdapter.cs(4,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
webapp\CaseDatabase.DataAccess\DBEntityCoreModel\CaseDatabaseContext.cs(2,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
webapp\CaseDatabase.DataAccess\DBEntityCoreModel\ICaseDatabaseContext.cs(2,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
webapp\CaseDatabase.DataAccess\DBEntityCoreModel\ICaseDatabaseContext.cs(3,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
webapp\CaseDatabase.DataAccess\DBEntityCoreModel\ICaseDatabaseContext.cs(4,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
webapp\CaseDatabase.DataAccess\EntityRepository.cs(4,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'EntityFrameworkCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: This issue seems relevant with dotnet restore. Did you have dotnet restore step before the build? If have, can you update question with your task configuration?

Comment: Can you please show us the complete devops pipeline?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT   added pipeline to the question

Comment: @Stella Have you tried using the .net core tasks? dotnet restore, dotnet build and dotnet publish?

Comment: @Stella, no error on your build argument. It's all work on my dotnet project. Your issue should caused by the package restore. Did you restore the package from feed and Org?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT  we use Nuget

Comment: @Stella, Got it. But I still want to know that in your nuget restore task, which package method are you using? From feed? Or also from Nuget.org? According to your error message, seemed you has package reference to EF, but lack it in the restore step.

Comment: @Merlin Liang - MSFT  WE selected from feed option

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT we selected from feed option

Comment: @Stella,Have you also enable the checkbox of `Use packages from NuGet.org`? Most time, we select feed and enable this checkbox to make the package restored completed.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Yes.We checked the use packages from NuGet.Org

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT please find the image added of Nuget restore task in question.

Comment: @Stella, I tested with asp.net and asp.net core(2.2) project which is using EFcore, all succeed with the same task with you. Do you mind share the **nuget restore task log**? And try with using `dotnet restore` task? If you convenient, we can create a chat room then help you troubleshooting qucklier, just free to leave comment here.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I don't enough reputations to create a change room...could you please create it and invite me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199886/discussion-between-merlin-liang-msft-and-stella).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the build log which shared from @Stella, this error message should caused by the package restored path.

Firstly, it's all succeed to restore the relevant package with the `Nuget restore` task. And also, the packages needed all has been restored. It's restored folder location is `D:\a\1\s\webapp\Websites\packages` which same with location defined in Nuget.config `..\packages`

In the `Visual Studio Build` log, there has the following message:

```
Considered "..\ThirdParty\NuGetPackages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll", but it didn't exist.
***
***
Considered "..\ThirdParty\NuGetPackages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll", but it didn't exist.
***
***
***
```

According to these message which displayed in Visual Studio Build task, you can see it is finding the package location under the folder path `..\ThirdParty\NuGetPackages`. As normal, this path is controlled by the `<HintPath>... </HintPath>`.

Now, it would be very easy to know the error caused: the package location which found during the build does not match with its actually package restored location in `Nuget restore` task.

As normal, its default location should be `..\packages\...`, which same with default location defined in `Nuget.config`. I assume its local repos path should ever be changed, then its `HintPath` which defined in `csproj` file are also be changed automatically. But, in Nuget.config, its package default location are still keep default. That will cause when package restore, it follow the location defined in `Nuget.config`. But during build time, since it look for the package with the `csproj` ...  defined, build can not know the actually package restored location. Then caused these error message.

---

To solve this issue, there has 2 solutions.

- Reinstall packages in Visual Studio

Run the below command to [reinstall all of packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages), thus the `HintPath` can all changed into default location `..\packages\...`, which can sync with defined in Nuget.config.

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

This logic of this solution is revoke `HintPath` as default location, thus it can keep sync with definition in `Nuget.config`.

After execute the command, the `HintPath` should same look as this:

[image]

- Modify the `Nuget.config` file

The logic of second solution is [modify the package location definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-2.1#specify-packages-folder-location) in `Nuget.config` file. Make it sync with `HintPath`, at this time, the location of the package restored will be the same as the location of the package at build time.

Add the following script into Nuget.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="xxxx" />
  </config>
  ... 
</configuration>
```

Just try with one solution, then build in Visual Studio locally. After it is succeed, then push it into Azure Devops, build with the same task configuration previously, `use nuget`, `nuget restore`, `VS build`, `publish artifacts`.

Hope this helps.