# WebApp and WebJobs deployment with Azure DevOps from same Repository

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

So, Azure has disabled adding WebJobs directly through the Portal, if source control (Git/Azure DevOps) is configured for that Web App. It gives an error message in the portal.
Now, as per this solution, WebJobs can be deployed if Virtual Application is configured and mapped to Release/Pipeline.

[WebJob cannot be added from portal if deployment form source control is configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972072/webjob-cannot-be-added-from-portal-if-deployment-form-source-control-is-configur)

After following the steps in that link and creating new Build/Release pipeline, I am facing following issues;

(Edited on 4-Oct-2019 12:30 PM UTC.)

[Here is how my Build Pipeline looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6ZjJ.png)

[WebJob fails during Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAgD7.png)

[Warning/Error messages of WebJob Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGLTa.jpg)

[Complete Build Log](https://pastebin.com/Yx5wqfZy)

```
WebJob Build
```

[Build Sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybAA1.png)

[Log with Nuget restore before WebJob build](https://www.transfernow.net/ddl/WebJobLog)

[Log after specifying Package directory Path](https://transfernow.net/ddl/WebJobLog3)

WebJob actually builds properly in local VS. Why does it fail during build?

Comment: What does " The individual CI Build Pipeline that I could newly add fails if I only add .NET Core build task." mean? Add .net core build task, then it will failed? What's error do you meet? Better update some screenshots about this.

Comment: I have added the screenshots. Could you please confirm?

Comment: Since you said that it can build in VS successfully, this means the error should not caused by package lack. Also, dotnet build has implicit restore, so the package should also be restored in azure devops. There has another error reason that the package restored path does not match the specific path in your csproj. Since you only share part of log, I am not sure this, you can refer to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58082935/11508165) for first self-check. This customer has the similar error with you.

Comment: If the error caused reason of this ticket does not match yours. You’d better share full log instead of partly of it. Because there many key info listed in logs.

Comment: I have added the log details. Can you suggest what needs to be done?

Comment: here please try 2 solution. One is add `nuget installer task` firstly before dotnet build task. And choose version higher than 4.3.0. The another solution  please refer to this [thread](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4280). In additon, the last two links seems be invalid. There's nothing listed in them.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try second solution. I already tried nuget installer before build, but it didn't work. Also, the last 2 links do give option to download the log files. You need to wait a while for that page to load and give download option.

Comment: Aha, I saw the download option, but confused by why need I download. So I closed the page then. Sorry, will download for details~ Addition, which type your webapp is? .net core?Or asp.net. This also very important to troubleshooting:-)

Comment: You get the log file download option below the Advertisement "download". The WebApp is in ASP.NET MVC. WebJobs is in .NET Core. And, they both reside in the same source code repository on Azure DevOps.