# Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' VSTS (DevOps)

Tags: c#, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

Please correct me where I am wrong, I keep getting above error in build pipeline event though I have setup the paths to be dynamic as follows:

```
     <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- EnlistmentRoot is the base directory where all of the module root directories reside. -->
        <EnlistmentRoot>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</EnlistmentRoot>
        <EnlistmentRoot Condition="'$(EnlistmentRoot)' != ''">$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(EnlistmentRoot)'))</EnlistmentRoot>
        <EnlistmentRoot Condition="'$(EnlistmentRoot)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(EnlistmentRoot)')">$(EnlistmentRoot)\</EnlistmentRoot>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- NuGetPackagesPath is the base directory for all nuget packages. -->
        <NuGetPackagesPath>$(EnlistmentRoot)..\packages</NuGetPackagesPath>
        <NuGetPackagesPath Condition="'$(NuGetPackagesPath)' != ''">$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(NuGetPackagesPath)'))</NuGetPackagesPath>
        <NuGetPackagesPath Condition="'$(NuGetPackagesPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(NuGetPackagesPath)')">$(NuGetPackagesPath)\</NuGetPackagesPath>
      </PropertyGroup>

 <Reference Include="EntityFramework">
      <HintPath>$(NugetPackagesPath)\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer">
      <HintPath>$(NugetPackagesPath)\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact">
      <HintPath>$(NugetPackagesPath)\EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Comment: Hi friend, just checking in to see if the issue persists you or not, if it still blocks you please feel free to let me know :)

Answer (score 2):

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in
> the namespace 'System.Data'

This error message indicates the build process can't find the assemblies coming from the restored nuget packages. So you should check the log of the `restore task` in build-pipeline to make sure the packages are restored successfully.

1.Make sure you have `use nuget` and `nuget restore` tasks before your `build` task like this (Avoid using dotnet related tasks cause your project targets `.net framework`):

[image]

2.And if the issue persists while the `nuget restore` task succeeds, check the logs of `nuget restore` task to find where the packages are stored:

[image]

And then check the logs of `build` task to know how msbuild recognize path like `$(NugetPackagesPath)\EntityFramework.6.1.3...` :

[image]

We should make sure the path where the packages are restored(restore task) and the path used by msbuild(build task) to get assemblies are the same! For this, you may get some help from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58025621/unable-to-build-a-asp-net-app-in-azure-devops).

**In addiion:** Not sure why you use customized `$(NugetPackagesPath)` instead of normal

```
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

For #2, you can also change the format of `<hintpath>` to normal way to check if the issue is resolved.

Hope it helps and if I misunderstand anything, feel free to correct me :)